# ##UserId## parameter is no longer automatically filled on Data Explorer

Tags: bug, data-explorer

If I go to e.g. [How many upvotes do I have for each tag?](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/785/how-many-upvotes-do-i-have-for-each-tag) while logged in at Data.SE, the `##UserId##` parameter isn't populated like it usually is. This was originally only happening for some sites, but now it seems to be happening for all of them.

Comment: Is your email set on Anime.SE? Data Explorer shows you have a null `EmailHash`, which is why it can't guess your ID.

Comment: @TimStone It is set (to the same email as on every other site where I have an account). I tried changing it to something else and then changing it back, and I'm still seeing the same behavior on the data explorer.

Comment: @TimStone As it stands now, I'm not getting my UserId auto-filled for _any_ of my sites.

Comment: @TimStone Yeah, same as Mark Hurd. Other beta sites like e.g. Japanese were working when I first posted this report, but now I'm not getting UserId auto-filled there, despite basically having not touched the account between January 15 and now. I don't get UserId auto-filled on non-beta sites either, like SO, MSO, SU, etc.

Comment: I think this is an effort to stop exposing `EmailHash`. Now that `AccountId` has been added to the `Users` table we can use that much more reliably anyway, so I'll make some changes to make that possible. /cc @MarkHurd